# SQL Login failed for user but connect fine in AWS Explorer - Eclipse

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, eclipse

So in Eclipse, I am trying to connect to a SQL server hosted in the AWS cloud.  I have opened the necessary network paths and I am able to connect by SSMS or another SQL client.  I am also able to connect in Eclipse by using the AWS Explorer plugin. When I try to connect by code, I am given the error message that the login failed for the user, SQLServerException.java:265 and a laundry list of additional errors.

Lost on this one at this point.

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());

conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://axxx.cxxxxt.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com", "User=sa", "Password=XXXXXXX");
```

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'User=sa'. ClientConnectionId:2360d78c-34ec-4004-ac9d-0313bf98e2c4
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:283)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:129)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5560)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4289)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:88)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4227)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7417)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3488)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2978)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2628)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2471)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1470)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:915)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
at process.Home$2.actionPerformed(Home.java:160)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70011472/edit) your question to include the actual error message - as text.

Comment: If you're able to connect from the same machine to the same server using the same `sa` user credentials then it's probably something Java-specific. It could even be something like a (really) old version of JDK/JRE that doesn't support TLS 1.2 connections. Or not trusting server's certificate... since SQL Server instances usually have a self-signed X.509 certificate by default.